# how to config webpack in a project created by vue-cli 3?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

By using vue-cli 3, I created a project with the following structure:
[image]

Then I hope it would support webpack. I tried to add webpack.config.js into build folder, and add script

`"webpack --config build/webpack.config.js"`

in package.json file.

However it seems that this doesn't work out with an error shows `"Error: Cannot find module '/Users/laiyinan/Documents/前端开发/稠行手机银行（个人）/build/webpack.config.js'"`

How could I use webpack in vue project? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can create your project with Vue `vue create myproject` - it will use Webpack out of the box. If you want to tweak the Webpack settings you will have to use `vue.config.js` file (https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html)

Comment: @IVOGELOV awesome document! But there is still one hiccup: I want to customize a plugin like this:      plugins: [
       {
   name:'less-theme',
   path:'src/components/common/theme.less'
  }
    ]

it doesn't work out here.

Comment: Read this part of the document (https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#modifying-options-of-a-plugin) - or use the example below by **DigitalDrifter**